# How to merge pandas columns within the same dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
    colA        ColB       ColC
0               D
1                           G
2   A       
3               B
4   C
```

How can I merge it into (*):

```
    colA
0   D
1   G
2   A
3   B
4   C
```

So far I tried to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.merge([df.ColA, df.ColB, df.ColC], how='right')
df
```

However, it doesn't worked. How can I get (*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydattotal_seca.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
df = df.sum(axis=1)
```

If `NaN` values you can [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) first:

```
df = df.fillna('').sum(axis=1)

print (df)
0    D
1    G
2    A
3    B
4    C
dtype: object
```

Another solution with `apply` - `join`:

```
df = df.apply(''.join, axis=1)
#df = df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)
print (df)
0    D
1    G
2    A
3    B
4    C
dtype: object
```

Solution with [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html), but need `NaN` values:

```
print (df)
  colA ColB ColC
0  NaN    D  NaN
1  NaN  NaN    G
2    A  NaN  NaN
3  NaN    B  NaN
4    C  NaN  NaN

df = df.colA.combine_first(df.ColB).combine_first(df.ColC)
print (df)
0    D
1    G
2    A
3    B
4    C
Name: colA, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks I got: `TypeError: join() takes no keyword arguments` with the second solution.

Comment: I add alternative solution `df = df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)`

Comment: Now I got: `TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`

Comment: Interesting, what is your pandas version? `print (pd.show_versions())`

Comment: It's `pandas: 0.19.0`!

Comment: What is `type(df)` ? It is `DataFrame` or `Series` ?

Comment: `pandas.core.series.Series` its a series

Comment: then use `df = df.str.strip()` if Series.